# ARM program memory dump

Tags: assembly, memory, arm, gdb, hardware

I'm being asked a question about a memory dump and how to find the values of the var x and y. I was wondering how I would find those I'll post the questions below.
-Thanks

```
 1  
 2 .global  main    @ main: is our entry point and must be global  
 3 .func    main 
 4 .data    
 5 .balign 4 
 6 x:       .word  ???? 
 7 y:       .word  ???? 
 8 string:   .asciz "????" 
 9 .text 
10 main: 
11  ldr r0, = x     /*r0 gets the address of  x*/ 
12  ldr r0, [r0]    /*r0 gets the content of the memory 
13                  /* pointed to by the the content r0*/  
14  
15  ldr r1, = y     /*r1 gets the address of  y*/ 
16  ldr r1, [r1]    /*r1 gets the content of the memory */ 
17  
18  ldr r3, = string /*r3 gets the address of  string*/ 
19  ldr r3, [r3]    /*r3 gets the content of the memory*/ 
20  
21  ????            /* What is this instruction */ 
22  ????            /*   What is this instruction  */ 
23  bx  lr
```

Some information needed are as follows:
After assembling. Linking, running, and gdp-ing, I typed the following gdb instructions:

```
(gdb) p/x &x 
$1 = 0x21024
```

The above command  indicates that the address of the variable x is 0x21024.

Then  I dumped the content of the memory, starting at the address 0x21024,
by typing  the  following command:

```
 (gdb) x/80b 0x21024 
 
0x21024: 0x63 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xc7 0xff 0xff 0xff 
0x2102c: 0x54 0x6f 0x20 0x42 0x65 0x20 0x6f 0x72 
0x21034: 0x20 0x4e 0x6f 0x74 0x20 0x74 0x6f 0x20 
0x2103c: 0x42 0x65 0x20 0x54 0x68 0x61 0x74 0x20 
0x21044: 0x69 0x73 0x20 0x20 0x74 0x68 0x65 0x20 
0x2104c: 0x51 0x75 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x69 0x6f 0x6e 
0x21054: 0x3f 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x2105c: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x21064: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x2106c: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Questions:
I ran the program then I replaced  the values of x, y, string by “?????

1. Using the above memory dump, what are the value in decimal of x and y (lines 6 and 7 The value x is positive and the value of y is negative.)
2. String (line 8)  is a message that you need to find.

I replaced the instructions at line 21 and 22 by xxxx and xxxxx
The code of the line 21 instruction is 0f 00 a0 e3  and the code  of the line 22 instruction
is 01 00 80 e0.
3. What are these instructions?

Comment: It's unclear what you're having trouble with exactly, since it seems that you have all the data you need. For 1 and 2, use a calculator and an ASCII table if necessary. For 3, use an ARM instruction set reference (e.g. ARM DDI 0100), which will contain the encodings of all instructions.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. We will expect you to work a little harder to solve this yourself. The encodings for ARM instructions (once you specify the exact architecture) are well defined...have you tried looking them up?